# jQuery Tools: Expose... API Problem

Tags: jquery, api, jquery-tools

I am trying to use jQuery Tools EXPOSE function. I have successfully implement the overlay tool as well as its API object (so I can call api.close()). I think I am having a problem with the initializing line and the proper object is not being passed to my API variable. You can see the error listed below in the comments.

**http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.3/full/jquery.tools.min.js**

```
var api;  
function exposeItem(v){

    api=$('#'+v).expose({
        api: true,
        color:'#000',
        loadSpeed:'fast',
        closeSpeed:'fast' 
    });

    api.load();  


    api.close(); 
    //Object #<an Object> has no method 'close'
 }
```

Any assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. It was so simple, it only took me a full day to figure out.

```
//api.close();
$.mask.close();
```